# Can not upload android library to JCenter repository in bintray.com

Tags: android, jcenter

The error is **could not create package 'maven' was not found**.

[image]

But I have created maven repository in bintray.com. Check the link and screenshot below

https://bintray.com/powerupcloudtech/maven/webviewoverlay

[image]

I followed below tutorials. But getting the same error for more than 2 days.

1.https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

2.https://www.numetriclabz.com/distribute-android-library-through-jcenter-from-android-studio/#Upload_library_to_jcenter

3.https://medium.com/@eliaslecomte/publish-an-android-library-on-jcenter-a37770dc9570

I am tired of trying all the solutions from the web.

Below is code that I used in library build.gradle

```
ext {
bintrayRepo = 'maven'
bintrayName = 'webviewoverlay'

publishedGroupId = 'org.pcc.webviewOverlay'
libraryName = 'WebViewOverlay'
artifact = 'webviewoverlay'

libraryDescription = 'A widget to load WebView as an Overlay.'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/itvignes09/WebViewOverlay'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/itvignes09/WebViewOverlay.git'

libraryVersion = '1.0.0'

developerId = 'powerupcloudtech'
developerName = 'vigneswaran a'
developerEmail = 'vignesh.m@powerupcloud.com'

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the build.gradle you attached, it seems that there are some misconfigurations.

We recommend you to review ['Bintray Examples'](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples) and the ['Gradle Bintray Plugin'](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin) in Bintray's GitHub.

If you still have any follow up questions regarding this, please do not hesitate to contact us at support@jfrog.com.

We hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try and let you know here

Comment: take a look at this config [bintray.gradle for upload to jcenter](https://gist.github.com/miguelhincapie/7ca32d25561fc74b3d4c497758d597ed). If it's useful for you, I can add complete answer with more details :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late now but it might help other people. **libraryName and artifact should and must be same the library module's name in your project**. Read the following article for more details, it states everything in details.

https://medium.com/@abhishekint16/upload-your-first-android-library-1892c23aea0f